# Why does the diffusion pole universally appear in the two-particle Greens function (diffuson)

Tags: condensed-matter, disorder

I've been thinking about the calculation of the diffuson in the context of impurity-averaged Greens functions.

If you calculate the two-particle Greens function in the ladder approximation (for example, in Rammers' "Quantum Transport Theory, p.337" or any similar textbook) you obtain the famous Diffusion propagator
$$
\frac{1}{1- \zeta(q, \omega)} = \frac{1}{i \omega - D q^2}
$$
Here the ladder insertion $\zeta(q, \omega)$ should be calculated using the integral of advanced and retarded Greens functions, and the answer should seem to be dependent on the dimensionality, the density of states and so on. Yet we universally have $\zeta(q\rightarrow 0, \omega\rightarrow 0) = 1$ exactly. This is clearly not accidental. Is there some simple way to prove that $\zeta\rightarrow 1$ exactly in the diagrammatic technique, independent of dimension, dispersion and so on?

Answer (score 1):

This can be derived using diagrammagic technique (see eg Altland and Simons' book). The more fundamental reason is that the diffuson is a Goldstone mode, which has to be massless (also see Altland and Simons).

But to my knowledge, the direct answer to your question is "no" -- there is no "simple" way because the math underlying the above is quite involved. This is unfortunate.